# Finding and deleting data from tables with same value in Sybase

Tags: sql, database, sybase, sql-delete

I am new to Sybase. I have requirement where I need to delete records from over 40 tables with same value in all the Sybase tables. following script gives all the Objects with the syscolumns. Is there way just select just tables and loop through each of tables (maybe using temp table) and delete records from all the tables where Employee_id is '101'

```
select   distinct object_name(id)
from syscolumns
where name = 'Employee_Id'
order by object_name(id);
```

Comment: Firstly bear in mind if you have foreign key constraints between tables you may need to do the deletes in a specific order. But once you confirm that the easiest way is you create the delete statement for each table into a string variable and execute it in a loop - see here:
http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36272.1550/html/commands/X30305.htm

Comment: there are no foreign constraints between tables